# The new pecl_http extension for PHP (version 2)

Tags: php

I just saw that there is a new version of the pecl_http extension available, see [the documentation](http://devel-m6w6.rhcloud.com/mdref/http). It brings a new interface and has no similarity to the old extension, so I would like to ask wether there are any examples on how to make the extension work? I installed it and the requirements raphf and propro, too. But even a simple

```
$client = new http\Client();
```

gives me a fatal error

```
Uncaught exception 'http\Exception\UnexpectedValueException' with message 'Failed to locate "(null)" client request handler' in
```

Same goes for

```
$client = new http\Client('curl');
```

just with `Failed to locate "curl"`.

I would like to see  a working example of the instantiation of http\Client and a simple GET request to a website.

Comment: Hi, a little bit off topic, do you know how to enable eclipse code assist  for pecl http?

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem on debian.

What helped is installing the nss version of curl:

```
apt-get install libcurl4-nss-dev
```

Then reinstall `pecl_http`, and give the following path when it asks for libcurl

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so
```

Comment: This is the right solution to this exact problem. Actually any of libcurl[34]-(openssl|gnutls|nss)-dev should do it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a cool gist, called [Using version 2 of PECL HTTP extension (pecl_http)](https://gist.github.com/ajaxray/11117042). I did not write this but it shows a few good examples of how to use version 2.

Comment: Hi, a little bit off topic, do you know how to enable eclipse code assist  for pecl http?

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation: http://devel-m6w6.rhcloud.com/mdref/http/

Example:

```
<?php
$client = new http\Client;
$client->enqueue(new http\Client\Request("HEAD", "http://php.net"));
$client->enqueue(new http\Client\Request("HEAD", "http://pecl.php.net"));
$client->enqueue(new http\Client\Request("HEAD", "http://pear.php.net"));

printf("Transfers ongoing");
while ($client->once()) {
    // do something else here while the network transfers are busy
    printf(".");
    // and then call http\Client::wait() to wait for new input
    $client->wait();
}
printf("\n");

while ($res = $client->getResponse()) {
    printf("%s returned %d\n", $res->getTransferInfo("effective_url"),
        $res->getResponseCode());
}
?>
```

http://devel-m6w6.rhcloud.com/mdref/http/Client/once

Comment: I tried this, but it still gives me the same error. I think there might be a problem with my extension, although I have reinstalled it twice and made sure that cURL, php-curl, php5-curl, propro and raphf are installed and loaded in the php.ini, so I don't know what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using redhat install curl-dev and then uninstall and install again pecl_http.

```
sudo yum install curl-devel
```

Hope this helps someone.